# Utilizing Sys:Addrr in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, module, ip, mac-address

The goal in the end is to create an ARP Listener and Sender using modules.

I am trying to substitute:

```
my $IP = "xx.x.x.xx"; #this is an actual local ip address
my $MacAddress = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"; # this is an actual macadd
my $LAN = "xx.x.x.xx/24"; #this has the ip and subnetmask
```

with a module `Sys::Addrr` to auto obtain the IP and LAN each time the program is run, this includes on different machines.

I have gotten the code down to this much using cpan- https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::HostAddr

```
my $sysaddr = Sys::HostAddr->new();
my $href = $sysaddr->ip();
 foreach my $interface ( keys %{$href} ){
     foreach my $aref ( @{$href->{$interface}} ){
          print " $aref->{address}\n"; 
          print " $aref->{netmask}\n";
     }
 }
```

BUT I am not understanding the sytanx of this code or structure enough to be able to pull only the first array reference for usage.  Using `Data::Dumper` I was able to see the break down to note that it's assigning the address I want to the [1](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::HostAddr) position, but I still can't seem to extract it for usage in the program.

I also noted that the MacAddress is not obtainable through `Sys::Addr`- I am assuming another module will be needed.

EDIT:
The information pulled when running it is:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'lo' => [
                    {
                      'address' => 'x.x.x.x',
                      'netmask' => 'x.x.x.x'
                    }
                  ],
          'eth0' => [
                      {
                        'netmask' => 'x.x.x.x',
                        'address' => 'x.x.x.x'
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

I am trying to extract the "eth0" contents in two variables for use in the program.

The full code without this new addition for reference of usage is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::Pcap::Easy;
use Net::Netmask;
use Net::ARP;
use Sys::HostAddr

my $IP = "x.x.x.x"; #IP Address omitted for example
my $MacAddress = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff"; #Mac Address omitted for example
my $LAN = "x.x.x.x/24"; # address omitted for example


my $parentpid = $$;
my $childpid = fork() // die "Fork Failed $!\n";

if ($childpid){
    print "perl lab6.pl $IP\n";
    print "Scanning $LAN\n";
    print "Starting parent $$ with child $childpid\n";
    print "Starting child pid $childpid\n";
    &send_loop;
    sleep 1;
    print "Killing child $childpid\n";
    kill 'KILL', $childpid;
    waitpid ($childpid, 0);
    print "Exiting parent $$\n";
    exit;
}
else {
    &cap_packs;
}

sub cap_packs{
    my $listener = Net::Pcap::Easy->new(
        dev             => "eth0",
        filter          => "arp",
        packets_per_loop    => 1,
        arp_callback        => sub {
                        my($npe,$ether,$arp,$header)=@_;
                        print "Hello";
                        if($arp->{opcode}==2){
                            my $iphex = $arp->{spa};
                            my @ip =($iphex=~/(..)(..)(..)(..)/);
                            my $ipstr = hex($ip[0]).".". hex($ip[1]).".". 
                            hex($ip[2]).".".hex($ip[3]);
                            print "Host $ipstr is alive.";
                            }
                        }
            );
    $listener->loop while 1;
}


sub send_loop{
    my $netobj = new Net::Netmask($LAN);
    for my $Remote_IP ($netobj->enumerate) {
        Net::ARP::send_packet(
            "eth0",
            $IP,
            $Remote_IP,
            $MacAddress,
            "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",
            "request");
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to access `$href->{$interface}[0]`?

Comment: Editing question to include output needed.

Comment: Try this: `my $netmask = $href->{$interface}[0]{eth0}[0]{netmask}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Sys::Addr` I figured out how to make it work properly.

```
my $sysaddr = Sys::HostAddr->new();

my $IP;
my $LAN;

my $href = $sysaddr->ip();
ints:foreach my $interface ( keys %{$href} ){
    foreach my $aref ( @{$href->{$interface}} ){
    $IP = "$aref->{address}\n";
        $LAN = "$aref->{address}:$aref->{netmask}\n";
    if ($interface eq "eth0"){last ints}
    }
}
```

That allows me to utilize the 'eth0' as a global variable.